# Checkbox manipulation

Tags: jquery

For some reason this little code is preventing the user from being able to check the actual checkbox and having it put the checkmark inside of it and the only way to get it checked is to click the row.

```
$('table tr').click(function() {

    checkBox = $(this).children('td').children('input[type=checkbox]');

    if(checkBox.attr('checked'))
        checkBox.removeAttr('checked');
    else
        checkBox.attr('checked', 'checked');

});
```

Comment: btw. checkBox.prop('checked', ! checkBox.attr('checked')) should be quicker

Comment: I don't understand that point of this code.

Comment: You think its un needed?

Comment: I don't know why I put it. My bad.

Comment: +1, the issue here is when you click the checkbox, the `$('table tr').click()` event fires before the checkbox's `click()` event. I'm wondering if it's possible to disable that behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are disabling the default checkbox behavior of the input is that the checkbox is inside the `tr`, so when you check the checkbox you fire your Javascript AND you toggle the checkbox... leading to nothing happening. You must check that the [**target of your event**](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is not a [**`:checkbox`**](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).

Also, there's no need to worry about the attribute of the checkbox... with jQuery, you can simply [**`.click()`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) it!

```
$('table tr').click(function(event) {      

    if (! $(event.target).is("input:checkbox"))
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').click();        
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/MgAza/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table tr').click(function() {
    $(this).find(':checkbox').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(this).removeProp('checked');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).prop('checked',true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This isn't working for me either. When I click the checkbox it isn't putting a check mark inside of it.