# jQuery Checkbox Click Sync (Regex needed)

Tags: jquery, regex, checkbox

I have two checkbox groups that I ultimately need to have one of them effect the output of the other. I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964495/checkbox-manipulation) question/answer which seems to have gotten me in a general direction, but there's some `regex` needed here, of which I'm not too familiar with.

Here is the first checkbox group:

```
<div class="tabs-panel" id="wood_types-all" style="display: block;">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="tax_input[wood_types][]">
    <ul class="list:wood_types categorychecklist form-no-clear" id="wood_typeschecklist">
        <li class="popular-category" id="wood_types-33"><label class="selectit"><input type="checkbox" id="in-wood_types-33" name="tax_input[wood_types][]" value="33"> Clear Pine</label></li>
        <li class="popular-category" id="wood_types-35"><label class="selectit"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="in-wood_types-35" name="tax_input[wood_types][]" value="35"> Oak</label></li>
        <li class="popular-category" id="wood_types-34"><label class="selectit"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="in-wood_types-34" name="tax_input[wood_types][]" value="34"> Poplar</label></li>
        <li class="popular-category" id="wood_types-36"><label class="selectit"><input type="checkbox" id="in-wood_types-36" name="tax_input[wood_types][]" value="36"> PVC</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The value I am trying to extract and compare is (for example), the `33` in `id="wood_types-33"`

The other checkbox group is:

```
<div class="field field-categories" id="acf-mp_wood_species_availability"><label for="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16]" class="field_label">Wood Species Availability</label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="33" value="clear-pine" name="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16][]" id="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16][]">&nbsp;Clear Pine
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="34" value="poplar" name="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16][]" id="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16][]">&nbsp;Poplar
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="" class="35" value="oak" name="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16][]" id="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16][]">&nbsp;Oak
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="36" value="pvc" name="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16][]" id="fields[field_4f7f4709cdb16][]">&nbsp;PVC         
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the two checkbox groups do share a common attribute `id="wood_types-33"`and `class="33"`.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is hide all of the second checkboxes by default (which I know can be done with):

```
$('#acf-mp_wood_species_availability li').hide();
```

and have the second group available to be selected (not selected, just `show()`) if a matching item from the first checkbox group is selected. I'm also trying to have it "look" for these matches on page-load (so if someone comes back to edit the item, the selections are available) and if an item from the first checkbox group is deselected (after being selected), then the second checkbox group item should not only disappear, but also uncheck (which can be done with `click()`). I've been at this a while and haven't gotten very far, so any help would really be appreciated. Thanks!

Starter jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JfwWv/

I saw [this](http://www.jquery4u.com/syntax/jquery-basic-regex-selector-examples/) which is a cheatsheet for regex in jQuery -- but I can't find any reference of the `match()` function --> am I just thinking of that wrong - is that the normal selector `$()` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numberToCompare = "#wood_types-33".split("-")[1];
```

Basically, calling `.split()` on a string returns an array of that string split on the character you specify. In this case, `"wood_types-33".split("-")` returns an array with two indexes, what comes before and what comes after the "-". We need what comes after; thus the `[1]` at the end.

Doing this would be faster:

```
var myStr = "#wood_types-33";
myStr = myStr.substr(myStr.lastIndexOf("-")+1);
```

But is a little trickier to explain. It just works. :p

Comment: Thanks for that @Elliot - tried to take this a bit farther, http://jsfiddle.net/JfwWv/1/ but don't think I'm approaching this correctly.

Comment: Let me take a look at it, I'll get back to you in a bit. I'm short on time right now so I can't promise anything, but...

Comment: @Zach: Here's a working jsFiddle demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/HeyJavascript/JfwWv/2/ I can't help you any further, I'm afraid. Good luck!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for taking the time to do that, have a great day!